# Jersey client - set IP address

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jersey-client

I have Jersey REST client:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(resource);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, requestEntity);
```

Server uses `@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;` to read sender IP  `httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`. Is there any way to set specific IP in header, property or other place from client side which can be read with `httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` on server side?

Answer (score 1):

The remote address header is part of the HTTP protocol and set by the client when a request is made. You may be able to write your own client or proxy to change this header, but its unlikely that a library will explicitly provide a way for you to do this.

Comment: If use simple URL / HttpURLConnection (https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) instead Jersey client library, is it possible to set remote address?

Comment: You'll need to look at the API documentation to find out.